# Xamarin Forms TemplateSelector for View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to use a TemplateSelector to select a View. Not for ListViewItems, like every example out there shows, but with a "normal" View. So i tried `TemplatedView`, `ContentPresenter` and `ContentView`. But non of them is able to take a TemplateSelector.

Is there something i have missed? Or how can i work around that?

EDIT:
I have a TemplateSelector, just like described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/). Now i want to add this Selector to some kind of ViewElement. Thats what i tried:

```
<TemplatedView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ViewItemTemplateSelector}"/>
```

or

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource ViewItemTemplateSelector}"/>
```

But nothing works, it always says "Invalid resource type"

EDIT2:

```
<ResourceDictionary MergedWith="dataTemplates:DataTemplates">
        <helper:ViewItemTemplateSelector x:Key="ViewItemTemplateSelector" 
                                         TextDataTemplate="{StaticResource TextDataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like a masterdetailpage or?

Comment: No, I just want to show a Control in a View. But this Control is always different, so a TemplateSelector should select a matching Template

Comment: You could perhaps make extends of this classes and use them in that way ? Or you could use a resource dictionary

Comment: I am currently using a ResourceDictionary, but how can i define the xaml to load from there? The TemplateSelector can not be set

Comment: `<TemplatedView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ViewTemplateSelector}" />` => Invalid resource type

Comment: Can you edit your post with the entire code ? i''m a bit confused atm and that would help to clear things up.

Comment: Could you add the code of your resourcedictionary of your contentpage? I think the problem lays there

Comment: Seems right, did you declare helper the right namespace / assembly?

Comment: Yes, it looks all fine, but i can only add a DataTemplateSelector to ListViews.

Comment: Is there a way to implement a ControlTemplateSelector?

Comment: Did you get a good answer?  I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following this guide of Xamarin?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/

Hope this works out for you.

EDIT:
Perhaps an alternative solution:
There are control templates but i don't think there is a selector for it. You could maybe use triggers for it? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/#Data_Triggers not sure if this is way you looking

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i did. But i do not want to add it to a `ListView`. I want it as part of a View within a Page. Is there no Control that wraps a DataTemplate? I realised this in UWP before, there i used `ContentControl` with a TemplateSelector

Comment: What kind of view do you want to use within your page?

Comment: It depends, thats why i need a TemplateSelector. But its always a Grid with some stuff in it

Comment: If this is a valid answer, don't forget to mark it as answer ;). I hope this solves everything, good luck!

Comment: I think it could work, so i marked it as solution. But I Realised it another way with a new class extending grid that shows a templatedview with a controltemplate inside.